# Get Lucene's n newest documents

Tags: .net, lucene

Using Lucene.net, how can I get the n latest documents that were indexed? (ideally with the ability to skip some because I need pagination as well)

The only solution I have found so far is to make a query that returns everything and sorts by date; but this is not efficient as we are in the 2-3 million documents range right now.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend adding another field and setting the current timestamp as a value. When searching, simply order by this field in descending order. When searching you can use custom collector to skip first X entries or simply use `IndexSearcher.searchAfter`. All above applies to Java Lucene and I'm guessing .net Lucene is no different in this sense.